# Wifi direct for 100 Devices, Write data to them and read back the output file from each

Tags: wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I need to know if it is possible to connect 100 Android devices using wifi-direct and transfer file of say 300KB to each and read back the output file from each device. Are there any limitations for this ? also can a device without wifi direct can participate in this application? If yes how?

Comment: I got some inputs that only 10 Clients can connect at a time. Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any docs that would specify limits to the connected clients, thus would assume that there is none.

For the second question, you could use the create Group function to create a group access point. Then you would need to find a way to distribute the automatically generated password and the SSID of the access point. If you can get those to the other devices, they can connect to the access point as they would connect to any normal access point.